# Toggle Class when element is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to build a function where when a link is clicked (all have the same class), a class is toggled on another element.

Example: if I click on link 1 red should get the class active. If I click on link 2, pink should get the class active and not the others and so on. My javascript knowledge is limited and I managed to give the link an active class but not the respective elements that I want to focus.

```js
$(".trigger").click(function(){
    $('.trigger').removeClass('checked') 
    $(this).addClass('checked') 
 })
```

```css
.main{
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}

.basic{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
}
.pink {
    background-color: pink;
    
}
.blue{
    background-color: blue;
   
}
.green {
    background-color: green;
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="trigger">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#" class="trigger">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#" class="trigger">Link 3</a>
  <a href="#" class="trigger">Link 4</a>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="red basic"></div>
        <div class="pink basic"></div>
        <div class="blue basic"></div>
        <div class="green basic"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `position: absolute` on your `basic` class is stacking the children on top of each other so setting any of them to `active` will cause no visual change so I've removed that property so you can see each element. Obviously you can style your elements as you wish.

I've set up a [custom attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) that lets your code know what element to apply the style (I've called it `data-target-class`). I've use jQuery's [attr method](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get that value in to a variable. I've then used jQuery's [child selector](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) to pick out all the children and remove the active class. I've used the same selector again to target the specific element you want and add the `active` class to that.

Finally I've created an `active` class that puts a [box shadow](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.php) around the element so you can see what's 'active'.

Hope this explains everything. If not pop a comment in and I'll see how I can make it clearer for you.

```js
$(".trigger").click(function() {
  $('.trigger').removeClass('checked');
  $(this).addClass('checked');
  const target = $(this).attr('data-target-class');
  $(".main > .basic").removeClass('active');
  $(".main > ."+target).addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-top:2rem;
}

.basic {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
  right: 0;
  margin:1rem;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.pink {
  background-color: pink;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.active {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px 5px #00FF0F;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="trigger" data-target-class="red">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="trigger" data-target-class="pink">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="trigger" data-target-class="blue">Link 3</a>
<a href="#" class="trigger" data-target-class="green">Link 4</a>

<div class="main">
  <div class="red basic"></div>
  <div class="pink basic"></div>
  <div class="blue basic"></div>
  <div class="green basic"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and for your very detailed description

Comment: My pleasure. It's a steep learning curve. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .main {
      position: relative;
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
    }

    .basic {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
    }

    .red {
      background-color: red;
    }

    .pink {
      background-color: pink;

    }

    .blue {
      background-color: blue;

    }

    .green {
      background-color: green;

    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".trigger").click(function () {
        $('.trigger').removeClass('checked')
        $(this).addClass('checked')
        let txt = $(this).text().trim();
        $(".basic").css("z-index", "0")
        if (txt == "Link 1") {
          $(".red").eq(0).css("z-index", "10");
        }
        else if (txt == "Link 2") {
          $(".pink").eq(0).css("z-index", "10");
        }
        else if (txt == "Link 3") {
          $(".blue").eq(0).css("z-index", "10");
        }
        else if (txt == "Link 4") {
          $(".green").eq(0).css("z-index", "10");
        }
      })
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#" class="trigger">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#" class="trigger">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#" class="trigger">Link 3</a>
  <a href="#" class="trigger">Link 4</a>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="red basic"></div>
    <div class="pink basic"></div>
    <div class="blue basic"></div>
    <div class="green basic"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

try below,

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".trigger1").click(function(){
                $('.basic:eq(0)').toggle();
            });
            $(".trigger2").click(function(){
                $('.basic:eq(1)').toggle();
            });
            $(".trigger3").click(function(){
                $('.basic:eq(2)').toggle();
            });
            $(".trigger4").click(function(){
                $('.basic:eq(3)').toggle();
            });
        })
```

```css
.main{
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}

.basic{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
     
    right: 0;
     
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
}
.pink {
    background-color: pink;
    
}
.blue{
    background-color: blue;
   
}
.green {
    background-color: green;
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="trigger1">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#" class="trigger2">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#" class="trigger3">Link 3</a>
  <a href="#" class="trigger4">Link 4</a>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="red basic"></div>
        <div class="pink basic"></div>
        <div class="blue basic"></div>
        <div class="green basic"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: not quite.

Only one of the basic classes should have an active. So if I click on link 1 red basic should have the class active and all others not. If I click on link 2. pink basic has the class active and all others do not.